# How to finish a container-managed transaction before running a long task?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, java-ee-7

I have a task which consists of 3 steps `prepare`, `execute`, `update`. `prepare` and `update` need to work within a transaction, whereas `execute` takes very long (i.e. several minutes up to hours). The task is part of an EJB, i.e.:

```
@Stateless
public class Task {
    public void doTask() {
        prepare();
        execute();
        update();
    }
}
```

My question is, is there an (elegant) way to commit and finish the transaction after `prepare` and start a new one before `update`? I'd rather use container-managed transactions and possibly not switch to use  `UserTransaction`.

It is possible to split the tasks into single EJBs if it gains any advantage, but note that suspending the transaction for `execute` (i.e. using `@Transactional(TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` is not enough since this still triggers the timeout.

I tried to split it into a `TaskExecute` class which has `@Asynchronous @Transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED) public void execute()` and sending an event when done. But this doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to do this?

---

After some further testing let me conclude: Alexanders reply was absolutely correct. My understanding had to be altered. Foremost, I wasn't aware that `@Transactional` does not work on EJBs, but only on CDI beans. For EJBs the annotation is called `@TransactionAttribute` and can be set to basically the same values. A combination of `@Asynchronous` and `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)` does work (if not waiting for the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of Java EE you want to use.  Here are three possible solutions.

- use JMS, send an appropriate message and do the `execute` in the MDB (any version, but full profile required)
- use Java EE 6.0's Timer Service and schedule a task to perform the `execute` asynchronously (`@Timeout`)
- use Java EE 7.0's Batch Processing API to schedule a proper long running batch job.

The latter is probably what you are looking for, but only available in Java EE 7.0 and up.  Otherwise, the JMS solutions is the cleanest, but if JMS is not an option, the Timer Service should work.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the Batch Processing API.